# add POST HOOK to a bitbucket repository using their REST API and python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to add a POST hook to a bitbucket repository, but I'm getting 404 results on each attempt.

I'm doing:

```
payload = {'type': 'POST', 'URL': announce_post_hook}
content_type = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
request_url = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{repo_owner}/{repo_slug}/services/'                       
request_url = request_url.format(repo_owner=repo_owner, remote_url=remote_url)
requests.post(request_url, auth=(repo_user, repo_pass), data=json.dumps(payload), headers=content_type)
```

I also tried using this URL:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{repo_owner}/{repo_slug}/services/
```

Since is the one listed in differnt parts of their api (and I'm using api.bitbucket.org instead of bitbucket.org/api/ to set up deployment keys, for example).

If I try to do it using curl, as in:

`curl -X POST -u user:pass https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/repowner/reposlug/services/ --data "type=POST&URL=https://hooks.urladdress.com"`

then it'll work. But attempting to do it through python-requests like in the other api call will fail...

Anyone has any idea on what's going on? It'll just respond that the resource is not found, which doesn't seem to be right (since it works through curl)

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935149/howto-use-python-urllib2-to-create-service-post-with-bitbucket-api) question with a very similar problem, but there are no answers there...

Comment: ended up sending the parameters directly through data, as in: requests.post(request_url, auth=(repo_user, repo_pass), data='type=POST&URL=https://hooks.url.com') and it works. apparently this particular endpoint doesn't like json encoded data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, if somoeone else has the same problem, apparently this particular endpoint doesn't accept json encoded data.

So the request would need to be

```
requests.post(request_url, auth=(repo_user, repo_pass), data='type=POST&URL=hooks.url.com')
```